# MongoDB geospatial index on point array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create a 2dsphere index on an array of (variable number of) [points](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#point) so that I can get the documents having at least one point within a given radius, and also the point(s) in the array that matched.
A document would look like this.

```json
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [8.17, 47.09]
    },
    {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [8.27, 48.09]
    },
    {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [8.37, 47.09]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create the index like this:

```js
db.test.createIndex({ "locations": "2dsphere" })
```

But it fails to create the index on these points. However, if I do

```js
db.test.createIndex({ "locations.coordinates": "2dsphere" })
```

it (probably) assumes [legacy coordinate pair](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#legacy-coordinate-pairs) syntax and creates the index. Also, if I do

```js
db.numbers.createIndex({ "thisIsANumberArray": 1 })
```

for an array of numbers, it creates a [multi-key index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#create-multikey-index) and works as intended as well.
What am I missing? Or is it how it is with MongoDB?

Now, the second method has the functionality I need, but I want to make sure if there is any disadvantage of doing that.

I tried using "MultiPoint"s like below too -- concise; however, it's hard to get the point(s) that matched.

```json
{
  "locations": {
      "type": "MultiPoint",
      "coordinates": [[8.17, 47.09], [8.27, 48.09], [8.37, 47.09]]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.